# Deconvolution Using Response to an Heavy Side

Tags: transfer-function, impulse-response, deconvolution, inverse-problem

I'm measuring a "charge" signal in function of time from an amplifier.
Here is a measured signal (x-axis is the time in some arbitrary units, y-axis is the charge in ADU):
[image: Measured signal (x-axis is the time in some arbitrary units, y-axis is the charge in ADU)]

I would like to get the "true", original signal, by deconvolving the instrument's response from the measured signal.

Here the response of the instrument to an Heaviside step function:
[image: Response to an Heaviside (x-axis is the time in some arbitrary units, y-axis normalized]

I guess this should help me characterize the instrument's response, and do the deconvolution. 
I read about SVD and Bayesian unfolding, but these don't seem to do the trick (I need to built a transfer matrix first).
Could you suggest me any tool/algorithm to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume no noise (Or the SNR is very high) you can get the response by applying the inverse filter in frequency domain.

Lets say $ y [n] $ are the signal samples.
Given $ x [n] $ the samples of the ideal signal you can apply on both of them the DFT to get $ Y [k] $ and $ X [k] $.

The response is given by the Inverse DFT of the division $ \frac{Y[k]}{X[k]} $.

If there's some noise you need to regulate the result.
Easy choice would be the [Wiener Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) or more specifically [Wiener Deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution).

Comment: Thanks! Tried what you proposed, assuming the red curve was instrument response to a Heaviside. Got strange (and obviously erroneous) results. It might actually be the response to a Dirac-like signal. I'll give it an other try.